# How do I use jQuery to scroll to a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<!--jQuery-->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#work-btn").hover(function() {
       $('.fa-caret-right').toggleClass('flip');
    });
    $("#work-btn").click(function(){            
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about-container").offset().top
            }, 500);
    });
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row text-center web d-flex" id="home">
  <!--  <img src="./jumbotron.jpg" id="home-img-web">-->
    <div class="col introduction flex-grow-1">
      <h1>Hello, I'm a front end web developer.</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col mt-2 work-btn">
            <a href="#">
              <button id="work-btn">View my work <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row text-center mobile d-flex" id="home">
  <!--  <img src="./jumbotron-mobile.jpg" class="flex-grow-1">-->
    <div class="col introduction flex-grow-1">
      <h1>Hello, I'm a front end web developer.</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <a href="">
<button id="work-btn-mobile">View my work <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--Navbar - Start -->
  <header class="sticky-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Navbar - End -->
    <div class="about-container" id="about-container">
      <div class="row text-center my-4 py-5" id="about">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="about" class="header-div mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h2>ABOUT</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-1.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Fast</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-2.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Responsive</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-3.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Intuitive</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-4.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Dynamic</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried at least 7 of the questions on here with similar questions and none of them worked for what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here so hopefully a different set of eyes can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to create a scroll animation to a the desired elements on click in jQuery. When I click it jumps to the element instead of smoothly scrolling which is my desired outcome.

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row text-center web d-flex" id="home">
  <!--  <img src="./jumbotron.jpg" id="home-img-web">-->
    <div class="col introduction flex-grow-1">
      <h1>Hello, I'm a front end web developer.</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col mt-2 work-btn">
            <a href="#">
              <button id="work-btn">View my work <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row text-center mobile d-flex" id="home">
  <!--  <img src="./jumbotron-mobile.jpg" class="flex-grow-1">-->
    <div class="col introduction flex-grow-1">
      <h1>Hello, I'm a front end web developer.</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <a href="">
<button id="work-btn-mobile">View my work <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--Navbar - Start -->
  <header class="sticky-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Navbar - End -->
    <div class="about-container" id="about-container">
      <div class="row text-center my-4 py-5" id="about">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="about" class="header-div mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h2>ABOUT</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-1.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Fast</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-2.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Responsive</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-3.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Intuitive</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
              <img src="./hex-4.jpg" class="about-icon">
              <h4 class="pt-2">Dynamic</h4>
              <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
                <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!--jQuery-->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#work-btn").hover(function() {
       $('.fa-caret-right').toggleClass('flip');
    });
    $("#work-btn").click(function(){            
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about-container").offset().top
            }, 500);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with duration number. For testing scroll velocity you can try *5000* instead of *500*.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference. It's still just jumping to the element regardless of the duration so the issue must be from somewhere else

Comment: Is there any particular reason you put <button> into <a> tag? Try to put it outside.

Comment: You can also try a built-in method scrollIntoView `$("#about-container")[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'start', inline: 'nearest', behavior: 'smooth'})`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. For some reason the version of jQuery that I had wouldn't cooperate but a different version worked perfectly fine.